# The reason why java process started by Maven cannot be stopped by Ctrl+C on Windows

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I created an executable Tomcat jar application that can be run by Maven (`mvn clean install exec:exec`). This application can be stopped by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on Linux. However, it cannot on Windows. Does anyone know the reason and solution?

**Environment:**

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.2 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2014-06-17T22:51:42+09:00)
Maven home: c:\apache-maven-3.2.2
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
Default locale: ja_JP, platform encoding: MS932
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

**Excerpt of pom.xml**:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>tomcat-run</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
                <enableNaming>true</enableNaming>
                <finalName>embtest.jar</finalName>
                <charset>utf-8</charset>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <warName>ROOT</warName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>startup-uber-tomcat</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-jar</argument>
                    <argument>target/embtest.jar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

(1) Run the commands on Windows:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/k-tamura/embtest.git
$ cd embtest
$ mvn clean install exec:exec
```

(2) Access to http://localhost:8080 -> Main page is displayed.

(3) Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

(4) Access to http://localhost:8080 -> Main page is still displayed (Tomcat is not stopped).

Comment: Does it open a console window separated from the one you executed? If so, select that console and hit CTRL+C and see what happens...

Comment: looks like you are executing maven goal, which runs the jar you are building. That's a bit weird. Did it work?

Comment: to: Jorge, No. Executed on one window.

Comment: to: Amarnath, I want to build the jar and run it with one command. Isn't it possible?

Comment: Note that in case of the maven-surefire-plugin ("maven test"), a similar issue has been fixed [as of version 2.19](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-524).

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev Thank you for your information. I'll check it.

Answer (score 1):

What actually happens when you start mvn is that you start a JVM instance outside the bash process. The output IS redirected to bash.

To avoid this, and maintain control over your bash shell, is to start the process in the background by adding &

```bash
$ mvn clean install exec:exec&
```

After this, you get output from the process. You can find the processes PID in the Windows context (!) by issuing ps

```
$ ps
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
     1475    1474    1475      15204  pty0      197610 10:38:32 /usr/bin/bash
     1666    1475    1666      18688  pty0      197610 10:54:48 /c/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-11.0.7.10-openj9/bin/java
     1685    1475    1685       4524  pty0      197610 10:54:57 /usr/bin/ps
     1474       1    1474      15544  ?         197610 10:38:32 /usr/bin/mintty
```

Here you can see that the Windows PID is 18688 for the Java runtime.

Now, you can kill this process by issuing taskkill on it, with the -f (force) option parameter:

```
$ taskkill -pid 18688 -f
SUCCESS: The process with PID 18688 has been terminated.
[1]+  Exit 1                  ./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

But the underlying Tomcat (or whatever servlet you're using) may still be running, if it has been started from the parent java session. To effectivly kill all (note: ALL) java processes, issue taskkill with -f on processes with the java.exe image name:

```
taskkill -im "java.exe" -f
SUCCESS: The process "java.exe" with PID 14452 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process "java.exe" with PID 12380 has been terminated.
[1]+  Exit 1                  ./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

It's litterally an overkill, but you're sure nothing java is running anymore.

Comment: `It's litterally an overkill`: well said! :)

Answer (score 0):

To stop all jobs:

```
mvn tomcat7:shutdown
```

When use combine keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, still has something working.

**Reference:**

http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/shutdown-mojo.html

Comment: I tried `mvn tomcat7:shutdown` but Tomcat was not stopped. Should I also change  my pom.xml?

Comment: Kill process `java` in Windows Task manager. If you can shutdown Tomcat server in Linux, I believe shutting down Tomcat in Windows are the same.

Comment: I know that task manager can kill process but I don't want to use it.

Comment: If possible, I want to shutdown by ctrl+c same as Linux.

Comment: Is there any update on this? I still have the same issue. When I run `mvn clean test`, I am not able to stop it using Ctrl+C.